# Lint warnings when using std::unary_function

Tags: c++, functor, lint

when checking a functor which is derived from std::unary_function as follows

```cpp
struct IsInterestingMsg : public std::unary_function<string,bool>
```

Lint ejects the following info/warnings:

```
1790: Base class 'std::unary_function<std::basic_string<char>,bool>' has no non-destructor virtual functions
```

and

```
Warning 1509: base class destructor for class 'unary_function' is not virtual
```

According to **Scott Meyers**, functor classes should be made adaptable by deriving from `unary/binary_function` which are basically *only a collection of typedefs*, thus, they are no classes that *need* any constructor / destructor. Therefore, the lint warnings are per se correct.

Does anybody know how to suppress these warnings *globally* and only for all usage of `unary_function` etc.? I want to avoid writing an `-e1509` every time it's used.

Info #1790 can be suppressed by using private inheritance instead of public, but warning #1509 remains.

Comment: Just bear in mind that `std::unary_function` is deprecated in C++11.

Comment: @juanchopanza The project must use the old C++. So C++11 can not (yet) be used, unfortunately. But thanks for the hint, I didn't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following suppression works for me:

```
/*lint -esym(1790, "std::unary_function<*,*>") -esym(1509, unary_function) */
```

There are a few pitfalls here:

- Note the quotes for the argument to esym, so Lint doesn't interpret the comma in the template parameter list
- Message 1790 is parameterized on a "Symbol" - thus you have to use the full namespace when refering to it
- Message 1509 on the other hand is parameterized on a "Name" so you're not supposed to give the complete namespace with it

As for when to use the namespace and when to omit it, just use the string that is quoted in Lint's error message, and it should be fine. The downside is that there doesn't seem to be a way to disable 1509 for std::unary_function, but not for ns::unary_function.

Comment: Thanks mate, that's exactly the solution I was looking for! Heck, it was the namespace! The hint how to distinguish "name" and "symbol" when creating suppressions is so important. Of course, it works for me, I can now suppress these warnings for unary_function globally without affecting other classes.

Answer (score 1):

Sigh, lint should have learned that... Anyhow, what you gain by deriving from unary_function is a few nested typedefs, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/unary_function/. You can create these yourself instead of inheriting them.

Another way would be to conditionally declare a virtual destructor in unary_function when lint is running. I personally wouldn't compromise perfectly valid code for the sake of lint though, neither in one way nor the other.

Comment: In this case, I would not twist my code *that* much just to satisfy lint--after all it's lint which is wrong here. What I was looking for is some way to tell lint not to raise #1509 or #1790 in the presence of `unary_function`, but neither `-esym` nor `-estring` or so do the job. So the least impact will be to add `-e1790` in front of the class declaration--and bite the bullet to do this in every similar case. In such rare cases I prefer this over global error code suppressions.